# return URL based on user input

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, conditional-statements, user-input

I am trying to download different product from a local website, for this I am using beautifulsoup.
I am trying to make my old code more flexible, so I want to include a user input feature, based on this the code would download what user inputed.

```
type = input("Please enter a product:\n")
print(f'Downloading {type}')

linkwm = f'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/stiralniye_mashiniy/almaty/90_6-90_1?page='
linkref = f'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/holodilniki/almaty/328_6-328_1?page='
linktv = f'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/led_oled_televizoriy/almaty/1285_1-1285_6?page='

if type == 'wm':
link = linkwm
rn = range(1, 4)
elif type == 'ref':
    link = linkref
    rn = range(1, 4)
else:
    link = linktv
    rn = range(1, 6)

print(link)
print(rn)
productlinks = []

for x in rn:
    r = requests.get(link + f'{x}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')
```

I have a problem with `r = requests.get(link + f'{x}')` I want URL in `requests.get` to add x to the end of URL, so the code would get info from all webpages in the range

Comment: i don't understand your issue, your iteration looks good. When your are iterating over the range are you getting the same webpage?

Comment: What error are you encountering?

Comment: It says     r = requests.get(link + f'{x}')
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'Tag' and 'str'

Comment: Basically, I can't iterate over pages

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid using python `keywords` as `variable name` [List of keywords](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords)

**Working example based on your code (input -> wm):**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

productType = input("Please enter a product:\n")
print(f'Downloading {productType}')

linkwm = f'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/stiralniye_mashiniy/almaty/90_6-90_1?page='
linkref = f'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/holodilniki/almaty/328_6-328_1?page='
linktv = f'https://www.sulpak.kz/f/led_oled_televizoriy/almaty/1285_1-1285_6?page='

if productType == 'wm':
    link = linkwm
    rn = range(1, 4)
elif productType == 'ref':
    link = linkref
    rn = range(1, 4)
else:
    link = linktv
    rn = range(1, 6)

productlinks = []

for x in rn:
    r = requests.get(link + f'{x}')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'lxml')

    for url in soup.select('div.goods-photo > a'):
        productlinks.append('https://www.sulpak.kz/'+url['href'])

productlinks
```

**Output:**

```
['https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_samsung_wf8590nlw9dyld',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f10b8nd_abwpcom',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_ww70j52e02wdld_8_623',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/ctiralnaya_mashina_samsung_wd70j5410awld',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f12b8wds7_8_817',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f2v5hs0w_8_628',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f2v5hs2s_8_629',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f2v5hs9b_8_837',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f1296hds4_8_823',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f1296hds0_8_825',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_samsung_ww70r421xtwdld_8_579',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_samsung_ww90k6414qwlp',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f1296nds3_8_821',
 'https://www.sulpak.kz//g/stiralnaya_mashina_lg_f2m5hs6s',
 ...]
```